# Converting Latitude and Longitude to coordinates on image

Tags: javascript, geolocation, gps, fabricjs, latitude-longitude

I am trying to convert a location to a point on image. I am using fabricjs to draw the map, the map object I made out of an image of the earth. I convert the image to an array, where land is 1 and 0 is water.
My problem is that I cant convert the location to a point properly.
I am using this formula which works, but not for the image I am using.

```
function getMapCoordsByLatAndLng(latitude, longitude, mapWidth, mapHeight){
    var x = (longitude + 180 )* (mapWidth / 360);
    var latRad = latitude* Math.PI /180;
    var mercN = Math.log(Math.tan(( Math.PI /4)+(latRad/2)));
    var y = (mapHeight / 2) - ( mapWidth *mercN/(2 * Math.PI));

    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
}
```

Here is my result for now.
[image]
I have used two locations - Los Angeles and Sydney. As you can see the coordinates on the map are not correct.
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nikksanus/kqbmr6v9/3/) with all the code.

Edit:
I ended up following a suggestion to use equirectangular projection instead of mercator one.
Thus the algorythm for finding the coordinates on the canvas changed.

```
    function getMapCoords(latitude, longitude, mapWidth, mapHeight){
        return {
            x: parseInt((longitude + 180.0) * (mapWidth / 360.0)),
            y: parseInt(((latitude * -1.0) + 90.0) * (mapHeight / 180.0))
        }
    }
```

I have updated my code and the result can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nikksanus/kqbmr6v9/5/).

Comment: What is wrong with the result? What did you expect as output?

Comment: @H.B. I edited the question, added image. The coordinates on the map are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map is off and the coordinates for Sydney are plain wrong.

With better coordinates:

[image: map]

Comment: Even if I correct the original image, Sydney will still appear way into the ocean.

Comment: Are you sure that your map is a Mercator projection then? I doubt that the code from that other SO question is wrong.

Comment: That must be the case, I will look for a correct image to use as a base.

Comment: @nikksan: Personally i would recommend an equirectangular projection, the code for converting the coordinates becomes dead simple :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems image has more than 360 degrees. You need to slice it properly.
Then divide by 360.

Or if you want to use it as it is, you need to add offsets.